# Extjs on a SVN Repository : required files

Tags: svn, extjs

I am creating a ExtJS application which must be sent on a SVN repository however Extjs files are sizeable. I would send only required files.

What are the minimum files required to make Extjs working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ext-all.js
- ext-all.css
- Images (Images which are using by CSS)

These things are required for ExtJs to work.

If you are using any plugins, you have check-in those files as well.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you do not need any of Ext files in SVN, only your application. I personally use Git and I always exclude `ext` library folder because developers only work on the application files.